# Laravel - find by custom column or fail

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

There's `findOrFail()` method which throws 404 if nothing was found, e.g.:

```php
User::findOrFail(1);
```

How can I find an entity by custom column or fail, something like this:

```php
Page::findBySlugOrFail('about');
```

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Page::where('slug', '=', 'about')->firstOrFail();    
// or without the explicit '='
Page::where('slug', 'about')->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: `Page::where('about', 'data')->firstOrFail();` this should work for equality operator '=' no need to put it explicitly

Comment: @Alupotha You can also do `Page::whereAbout('data')->firstOrFail();`

Comment: we need samples for more where methods like this that worked after models. is there any article that on laravel... any knowledge base?

Comment: I using findOrFaild and got tow few parameters error, but when using firstOrFail my problem resolved.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**
I'm currently using Laravel 6.9.0 and I confirm that @jeff-puckett is right. Where clause works fine. This is how it works on my tinker.

```
>>> \App\Models\User::findOrFail('123b5545-5adc-4c59-9a27-00d035c1d212');
>>> App\Models\User
     id: "123b5545-5adc-4c59-9a27-00d035c1d212",
     name: "John",
     surname: "Graham",
     email: "john.graham@test.com",
     email_verified_at: "2020-01-03 16:01:53",
     created_at: "2020-01-03 16:01:59",
     updated_at: "2020-01-03 16:01:59",
     deleted_at: null,

>>> \App\Models\User::where('name', 'Buraco')->findOrFail('123b5545-5adc-4c59-9a27-00d035c1d212');
>>> Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/ModelNotFoundException with message 'No query results for model [App/Models/User] 123b5545-5adc-4c59-9a27-00d035c1d212'


>>> \App\Models\User::where('name', 'John')->findOrFail('123b5545-5adc-4c59-9a27-00d035c1d212');
>>> App\Models\User
     id: "123b5545-5adc-4c59-9a27-00d035c1d212",
     name: "John",
     surname: "Graham",
     email: "john.graham@test.com",
     email_verified_at: "2020-01-03 16:01:53",
     created_at: "2020-01-03 16:01:59",
     updated_at: "2020-01-03 16:01:59",
     deleted_at: null,
```

**Outdated:**
It took at least two hours to realize that if you chain firstOrFail() method after where() in **Laravel 5.6**, it basically tries to retrieve the first record of the table and removes where clauses. So call firstOrFail before where.

```
Model::firstOrFail()->where('something', $value)
```

Comment: hmm, I think you must have some other problem. the where clause going first works fine for me in laravel v5.6.23

Comment: Yep! It work's but the difference is, in this example querying database then using `where` helper of collections. I meant querying database with `where` clause before it turns into collections.

Answer (score 6):

```
## Or Via Scope For Multiple Rows ##

public function scopeGetOrFail ($query)
{
    if (empty($query->count())) {
        abort(404);
    } else {
        return $query->get();
    }
}

Page::whereSlug('about')->getOrFail();
Page::where("slug","about")->getOrFail();
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion maybe you can define function getRouteKeyName() to explicitly taken the column you want when you use static find() for eloquent model.

```
public function getRouteKeyName(){
  return 'slug';
}
```

And if you insist, you can write it as static function inside model

```
public  static function findBySlugOrFail($value){
  //get slug collection or return fail
  return Post::where('slug', '=', $value)->firstOrFail();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
Page::where('slug', '=', 'about')->get()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).