# Laravel 5.5 - findorFail and check for another value

Tags: laravel

I am using try in Laravel 5.5 like this...

```
try {
        $fruit = Fruit::findOrFail($id);
    }
```

But I would like to check that not only that it finds the Fruit with the supplied ID but that it also has a fruit_color of 'red'

Do I need to do this with a 'with' statement?

I know I can run another check afterwards but wondered if I could do this all in one statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - find by custom column or fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212982/laravel-find-by-custom-column-or-fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things. First, throwing an exception here is the wrong way to handle the ‘if’ situation. If you plan on a situation where a value isn’t return, then this isn’t the proper use of an exception.  To answer your question:

```
$fruit = Fruit::where(‘id’, $id)->where(‘color’, ‘red’)->get();
```

This returns a **collection** of items meeting your criteria. Next to test if the collection is empty (no fruit) you can do the following:

```
if($fruit->isEmpty()) {
    //handle empty collection
}
```

Hope this helps! The Laravel documents for collections kicks a**. I’d recommend reading further there.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add your extra conditions in before you call the find:

```
try {
    $fruit = Fruit::where('fruit_color', 'red')->findOrFail($id);
}
```

Comment: A try statement should catch.. However, excluding the try, using `findOrFail()` at the end after the `where` methods seems to work when you need to filter the db results by particular where conditions and throw a 404 if there are no matches, all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$fruit = Fruit::where(‘id’, $id)->where(‘color’, ‘red’)->first();
```